# Empty model in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble getting model binding to work in the newish ASP.NET Web API.

I'm using jQuery to make my posts, and the client-side JavaScript looks like so:

```
function postJsonSettings() {
    return {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    };
}

function createCustomer(customer) {
    var settings = postJsonSettings();
    settings.data = JSON.stringify({ model: customer });
    return $.ajax(Payboard.Util.getAbsoluteUrl('/api/customers'), settings);
}
```

The request that results looks like this:

```
POST /api/customers HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.payboard.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 89
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://www.payboardapitest.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://www.payboardapitest.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

With a POST payload like this:

```
{"model":{"ExternalCustomerId":"6c5015c8-d04e-4309-a493-ec0355d1b3a0","Name":"asdfasdf"}}
```

The C# Web API method that gets called looks like so:

```
// POST api/customers
public void Post([FromBody] CreateCustomerModel model)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

With a CreateCustomerModel that looks like this:

```
public class CreateCustomerModel
{
    [Required]
    public string ExternalCustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `CustomerController.Post()` method gets called, and the `model` itself isn't null, but the `ExternalCustomerId` and `Name` properties are.

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying removing the 'model' in your JSON payload and just send the values for your CreateCustomerModel object.  I.e.

```
{"ExternalCustomerId":"6c5015c8-d04e-4309-a493-ec0355d1b3a0","Name":"asdfasdf"}
```

Comment: That was it - thanks. Another one of those subtle differences between model binding in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API.